# Возможно ли вывести огромное сообщение одним fmt.Println

Tags: golang

Даже не знаю как правильно описать ситуацию... Мне нужно вывести логотип в консоли Golang задействовав только один метод `fmt.Println() или fmt.Print`, тоесть должно быть что-то вроде этого:

```
        fmt.Println("

  _   _   _               
 | \ | | (_)   ___    ___ 
 |  \| | | |  / __|  / _ \
 | |\  | | | | (__  |  __/
 |_| \_| |_|  \___|  \___|


        ")
```

Но у меня ошибка синтаксиса. Возможны ли другие методы? Пробовал в `двойных скобках, fmt.Print, fmt.Sprint, fnt.Printf и т.д`, результата не было.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [необработанный строковый литерал](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals):

```
fmt.Println(`

    Number One

`)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/9NpUA-APnN.

Comment: спасибо, все работает

Comment: а что делать если допустим у меня в надписи присутствует `, синтаксис будет опять неправильным, или по другому нельзя?

Comment: @JackSmith В таком случае придётся извратиться: https://play.golang.org/p/Q7-28jDFF0.

Comment: я могу вывести Nice, но не могу вывести Totemplant : https://play.golang.org/p/YI5WtBQdup

Comment: @JackSmith Плохо стараетесь. https://play.golang.org/p/FJOkhWZirk. Экранировать двойными кавычками надо все обратные.